# how detect if node.js spawn need input?

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

detect state of spawn process if is sleeping in an uninterruptible wait. by node.js windows.

// possible values for State value in /proc/pid/status 
 // R running, 
        // S is sleeping, 
        // D is sleeping in an uninterruptible wait, 
        // Z is zombie (not running but held by process owner)
        // T is traced or stopped

```
 var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
 var sh = spawn("java", ["Test"]);

  sh.stdout.setEncoding("utf8");
  sh.stderr.setEncoding("utf8");
  sh.stdin.pipe(process.stdin);
  sh.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if () {//check if sh need input 
          sh.stdin.write("ddssd");
          sh.stdin.end();
      }
  });

  sh.on('exit', function(ecode) {
      console.log(ecode);
  });

  sh.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to detect that.  If it needs input, you can just write to the stdin and it will read it when it needs it -- if it is able to read from stdin at all like that.  If that doesn't work, the Java program may think it doesn't have an interactive terminal.  In that case, you can try `pty.js`.